# Home network infrastructure

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, repeater

The picture below is the infrastructure of my home network. I have one modem and one WIFI router and two WIFI repeaters. I didn't change any options in the router and repeaters (DHCP or anything else).

I have the problem that after 10 days of use I get the error that I cannot get IP address. Than I do a factory reset of the modem, router and repeaters and setup, always in the same way.

I know that I do something wrong, but I need help from someone who knows how to do this better.

Should I disable DHCP or give static IP addresses?

[image]

Comment: On which computer are you getting this error (home ?, pc connected to repeater 1 or 2 ?)

Comment: Questions: (1) Where are DHCP addresses allocated? (2) Does it help if you enter these commands on the computers : ipconfig /release and ipconfig /renew? (3) Do you often restart the DHCP server? (4) Did you check for firmware updates for router and repeaters? (5) Is there a possibility that you have more than one DHCP server? (6) Do you still have Internet after you get this error message? Remark: If you cannot find the problem, then static IP should fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is most likely a firmware error (and possibly a problem with running 2 repeaters).  You should upgrade your firmware and jump up and down at your vendor if that does not fix things.  That it works for 10 days implies it's most likely not a config problem.

That said, repeaters are ugly and waste bandwidth. You would change the repeaters to AP's and run a cables from the APs back to the router if this is an option.